# SSHD accept connections only from its own tunnel

Tags: security, ssh

I have a machine behind a firewall which is accessible from my server via a reverse SSH tunnel.

I would now like to prevent everyone from logging in to the machine IF they came from the ssh tunnel connection.   Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the match directive in sshd_config to *not* provide a shell for connections coming from a specific ip address

```
Match Address 10.1.1.1/32
ForceCommand /bin/false
```